# jquery load() issue with ie7 ie8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, modernizr

Hi this code does not run under ie7/ie8 for some reason.

```
$('#cnt').load('./tiles/pages/'+ $name +'.php #'+$lang, showNewContent());
```

It seems to have problems to retrieve the section in the php file with the id $lang. The code works in all other browsers, and it works in ie7/ie8 if I call it like that:

```
$('#cnt').load('./tiles/pages/'+ $name +'.php', showNewContent());
```

and I don't like that.

Any idea why ie7/ie8 behave this way? ok ie7 I know => it is crap :-)

For now the php file just contains plain html5 which looks like that:

```
<article id="de">
        <header>
            <h2>Your article heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </header>
        <h3>A smaller heading</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>   
        <h3>A smaller heading</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <footer>
        <h3>About the author</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </footer>
</article>
<article id="en">
        <header>
            <h2>Your article heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </header>
        <h3>A smaller heading</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>   
        <h3>A smaller heading</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <footer>
        <h3>About the author</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </footer>
</article>
```

**UPDATE:**

As it looks like, it is the HTML5 tags that throw it off??? I am using modernizr, anyone want to take a hit on that? In the dom only `<article id="de" />` is loaded the rest is neglected.

Comment: Maybe remove the space between php and #? Just guessing anyway... I hate ie =(

Comment: @Francisco, it's a start

Comment: include the rest of your script, what does $name / $lang equal, is this php echoing javascript?

Comment: $lang will be either 'de' or 'en' in this scenario. $name will be the file name slug refering to a url, e.g 'home'. Thus it would try to load 'home.php #de' which should load the <article id='de'> as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1**

You said that calling the code without # works ok, so since with the load method and ID selector you are actually fetching all the document, but jQuery will only keep the code within the specified element ID, you could simply call the load method without an ID selector, then keep only the element you need and remove the rest yourself.

---

Maybe the space in the URL is the problem, could you try to escape it somewhat?

Like

```
$('#cnt').load('./tiles/pages/'+ $name +'.php%20#'+$lang, showNewContent());
```

or

```
$('#cnt').load('./tiles/pages/'+ $name +'.php%2520#'+$lang, showNewContent());
```

Comment: Hi Jose, it is not the space in the URL. As by http://api.jquery.com/load/ it should not be anyhow. I have notices that if I replace the html5 tags back to 'normal' div and p tags it works also in ie7 and ie8

Comment: I update my answer, I think you could just load the document without the selector and keeping only the element/s you want, removing the rest with .remove(), or copying the element you need somewhere, then use .empty() to clear all content and append the element you copied before.

Comment: yeah I could but that is a lot out of the way if it should work just as stated in the jquery docs. I get it to work without any html5 tags so I guess that'll do for me ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but did you try re-applying modernizr on your newly loaded html?

Comment: ya too late =) I think I used plain xhtml then =) but thanks for the answer anyhow =)